# ContextMenu enabling issue

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, contextmenu

For the `body` tag I have `contextMenu` disabled.

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
```

But in my application one element, which is inside the body, needs the right click enabled. How to enable it for one particular div/element?

Answer (score 2):

Inside the oncontextmenu handler, check if the target element has a particular `id`, `className` or some other property.

```
document.body.oncontextmenu = function (e) {
    if (e.target.id !== 'that-div') { return false }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/eWBUR/